# Cannot add labels to a dataflow job

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-dataflow

after adding `additionalUserLabels` to runtime environment of a dataflow job created by `dataflow.projects.locations.templates.create` ( Node SDK), dataflow fails to retrieve the job graph and no other error is shown in the logs.

When not using `additionalUserLabels`with the same job configuration, everything works.

**Steps to reproduce:**

lunch a dataflow job from a template (Node SDK) by using  :

```js
const ressource = {
          location: process.env.PIPELINES_LOCATION,
          environment: { tempLocation: myPipeline, additionalUserLabels: {'client_id': clientId}},
          jobName: myJobName,
          gcsPath: mygcsPath,
          parameters: myParameters
        }

dataflow.projects.locations.templates.create({
            projectId: myProject,
            location: myLocation,
            resource: ressource
          })
```

Comment: Hi there, can you please copy and paste the error message you received?

Comment: Hi, I posted the issue on google issuetracker and got a response from the team https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136490191

Comment: the error shown on dataflow UI: dataflow fails to retrieve the job graph